# Netflix bandiwth usage changes when using router and hotspot

Tags: router, bandwidth, netflix

I came across a strange situation at a friend's home.

She has a Samsung smart-tv with Netflix on it, which connects to the Internet with a 4G router through WiFi. In this setup the bandwidth is as expected roughly around 3GB/h for a 1080p stream.

If she connects the same TV to the internet through her smartphone's hot-spot, a same-length content uses ~400MB, which is also the size of an hour-long content downloaded on my smartphone by the Netflix app.

The bandwidth consumption are those monitored by the internet company, which is the same for both the 4G router's SIM and the smartphone. The contract is also the same.

We are sure that the TV is the only device on the router (changed wifi name and password, enabled ACL with only TV whitelisted, etc).

So, I don't know what is going on...

Comment: Netflix content scales to your connection (only limited by your account level).  A phones hot spot is often restricted by a mobile phone provider

Comment: But both connection are 4g-based, with the same carrier and same contract.

Comment: Still doesn’t change the fact Netflix scales to the connection and there is a difference between a 4G router and a hotspot created by a 4G phone

Comment: So Netflix does not use the information "this is a mobile connection" but uses the information "this connection comes from a router or from a smartphone"?

Comment: [Fast.com](https://fast.com/) is ran by Netflix and should give you some insight into your connections.  I can't guarantee you the results are identical to that of Netflix.com but I do know Netflix scales content.  So the only way one connection would use more bandwidth in an hour is if the content was higher quality.

Comment: Is not a problem of speed (which is the same in both connections), but of size of data transfered.
Content scaling is a client setting, and the client is the same, so I don't think this is a factor in the equation...the only thing that changes is the hardware between TV and the 4G antenna of my ISP.

Comment: Please try to use a sentence that represents a question. You are describing stuff followed by telling that you don't know what is going on. Asking a specific question gives you better chances to receive a specific answer.